# How to make a query with Eloquent in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

What I want to do is the equivalent of this consultation using Eloquent, but I have no idea how to do it.

```sql
update promociones set veces_cajeadas=veces_cajeadas + 1 where id = 7
```

What I need is that when a specific promotion id is chosen, add 1 to a field in the table. The model for the table is Promotions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in laravel eloquent and even query builder, there is a convenient way to decrease and increase values of model

```
$promotions = Promotions::find($id);
$promotions->increment('veces_cajeadas')
```

for more information about these methods you can read [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#increment-and-decrement)